# Why would I put a vector on the heap?

Tags: c++

Why would I ever put a vector on the heap?

I saw code like this pretty often:

```
std::vector<int> *v = new std::vector<int>();
```

The only reason I can think of is if I want to share this vector, so in modern C++ I would use a shared_ptr.

Are there other reasons for putting a vector on the heap? I mean the elements in the vector are already heap allocated.

Comment: That seems to sum it up, if we speak of C++11 and later. Remember there were no move-semantics earlier, though there already was return-value-optimization.

Comment: If the vector was created within a function and you want to return a copy of the vector. Then allocating the vector on the heap and returning a pointer to it, would allow access outside the function.

Comment: You would only ever need to put a vector on the heap if you need a multidimensional dynamic array (i.e `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`)

Comment: In general this is either somebody not understanding how stl containers work or because they wanted to avoid a copy

Comment: @cppcoder, If you want to return a copy of a vector created in a function, make the return type `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Without seeing the context of such code, we can only speculate why someone would want to put a `vector` on the heap.  But in general, putting *anything* on the heap keeps it off the stack and extends its lifetime beyond the current scope.  That can be useful at times, even for STL containers, depending on how they are being used.

Comment: If a vector is created in a function and returned (as a copy) by the function, are the elements also copied (which would mean allocating heap space, copying the elements, then freeing the old elements)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of whether an object should go on the stack or on the heap or be static is all about lifetime. Short-lived objects should (usually) go in registers or on the stack; long-lived ones on the heap; and permanent ones static.

So the answer is yes, you put a vector on the heap if it is expected to have a long life-time, but shorter than the lifetime of the program.

The question of a shared pointer only applies if something is to be shared, which is a different consideration again.

[HT @Eric Lippert for pointing this out in the context of C#]

Comment: The "lifetime" is more about scope than time. If something must continue to live beyond the current code block, it *can't* be on the stack. And `shared_ptr` is useful beyond the sharing of pointers as it also controls lifetime, although `unique_ptr` is sometimes more appropriate - see the scope comment again.

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, scope is something different again. Scope is the largest part of the program in which a name is valid (S3.3.1) but lifetime is a runtime property of an object defined in S3.8, related to storage duration in S3.7. An object can have block scope and still be static or extern.